# How to HASH VARCHAR2 to Alphanumeric with DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.MD5

Tags: sql, database, oracle, md5

i have 3 variable name,password,mail. I want to hash them like name-password-mail with MD5. When i use this code:

```
SELECT sys.DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.MD5(INPUT_STRING => 'hurricane-1234-mail@mail.com') FROM DUAL
```

output look like :

```
8����n�iB
```

I want to hash this Alphanumeric. Like(random example);

```
AD63Ss32S32casad23D
```

Is there any way do that with MD5 or which ORACLE SQL function do that like what i want.

Comment: You maybe want to convert to/from RAW. But how will you store and use this value? And which version of Oracle are you using - if 11g you can use `DBMS_CRYPTO` instead, and this is now deprecated.

Comment: I am using oracle 10g. That function doesn't work. I wanna that hash to unique identifier for me.

Comment: OK, but you'd need to treat it as RAW to see the hex values; so you should store/retrieve it as RAW too. And you know a hash isn't unique,  right?

Comment: Yeah. I will use for maximum 10 row table :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert your input string to RAW and pass that in, getting a RAW value back:

```
select dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.md5(input =>
  utl_i18n.string_to_raw(data => 'hurricane-1234-mail@mail.com')) from dual;

0B38E5C219F8E40CADD2156ECBCB6942
```

Or pass a string in and convert the result to RAW:

```
select utl_i18n.string_to_raw(data => dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.md5(
  input_string => 'hurricane-1234-mail@mail.com')) from dual;

0B38E5C219F8E40CADD2156ECBCB6942
```

---

You said in a comment you're on 10g, but if you were on 11g or higher you should consider moving to DBMS_CRYPTO instead, as DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT is now deprecated. You can't use it from plain SQL though, as the `typ` parameter is PLS_INTEGER, but as an example call from a block:

```
set serveroutput on
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(dbms_crypto.hash(src => utl_i18n.string_to_raw(
    data => 'hurricane-1234-mail@mail.com'), typ => dbms_crypto.hash_md5));
end;
/

anonymous block completed
0B38E5C219F8E40CADD2156ECBCB6942
```

Comment: Ty for your share. I am using 10g and RAW value is enough for me. Good evening.